# Shorten WHILE to a single UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble constructing a concise update statement. Here's a fiddle to a sample DB: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6899b0

It contains tables of customers with multiple addresses.

Now I need to convert `ABadrestype = '-1'` entries in `[AdresBewoners]` using this logic:

- Only convert if `ABtypebewoner = 'K'`
- If the customer already has a principal address (`ABadrestype = '1'`), then update it to `'2'`.
- Else, convert the first to `'1'` and, if multiple, any others to `'2'`

Here's the expected result (annotated next to the sample db seed statement to clearly see what needs to be updated):

```
[dbo].[AdresBewoners] VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 'K', '1'),
    (2, 2, 1, 'K', '2'),
    (3, 3, 2, 'K', '2'),
    (4, 4, 2, 'K', '-1'), -- change to 1, as it's the first for a customer without a principal address
    (5, 5, 2, 'K', '-1'), -- change to 2, as it's the second for a customer without a principal address
    (6, 6, 1, 'K', '-1'), -- change to 2, as the customer already has a principal address
    (7, 7, 3, 'Z', '1'),
    (8, 8, 3, 'Z', '-1')  -- leave as is; "Z" denotes other entity type
```

Can this be done in a single update statement?

**EDIT**: this is the `WHILE` equivalent:

```
-- Fetch affected records.
INSERT INTO
    #tmp_adresbewoners
SELECT
    ABid,
    ABidB
FROM
    AdresBewoners
WHERE
    ABtypebewoner = 'K'
    AND ABadrestype = '-1'

-- Declare cursor
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR
DECLARE @ABid int
DECLARE @ABidB int

SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        ABid,
        ABidB
    FROM
        #tmp_adresbewoners

OPEN @cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @ABid, @ABidB

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    UPDATE
        AdresBewoners
    SET
        -- If no principal address exists for the current customer, use '1', else use '2'
        ABadrestype = CASE
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT ABid FROM Adresbewoners WHERE ABidB = @ABidB AND ABtypebewoner = 'K' AND ABadrestype = '1') THEN '1'
            ELSE '2'
        END
    WHERE
        ABid = @ABid

    FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @ABid, @ABidB

END

CLOSE @cursor
```

Question remains the same: can this be done in a single UPDATE statement?

Comment: How do you define first?  Is this the record with the lowest `ABid`?

Comment: Perhaps you could include what [you've done so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? Also, is *all* that schema relevant to the problem?

Comment: @destination-data Yes, the lowest ABid is fine.

Comment: @KtX2SkD I'd like to, but I didn't manage to get beyond a regular update with some tables joined... The conditional part is puzzling me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want insert the records which you want and avoid updation over your table

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AdresBewoners] 
select [ABid], [ABidA], [ABidB], [ABtypebewoner],
       coalesce(case when (ABtypebewoner = 'K' and [ABadrestype] = -1) then null else [ABadrestype] end, 
               case when lag(ABadrestype) over (order by ABid) <> [ABadrestype] then 1 else 2 end) [ABadrestype]
from
(
    VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 'K', '1'),
    (2, 2, 1, 'K', '2'),
    (3, 3, 2, 'K', '2'),
    (4, 4, 2, 'K', '-1'), -- change to 1, as it's the first for a customer without a principal address
    (5, 5, 2, 'K', '-1'), -- change to 2, as it's the second for a customer without a principal address
    (6, 6, 1, 'K', '-1'), -- change to 2, as the customer already has a principal address
    (7, 7, 3, 'Z', '1'),
    (8, 8, 3, 'Z', '-1')  -- lea
)a([ABid], [ABidA],[ABidB], [ABtypebewoner], [ABadrestype])
```

**AND** If you want to force your update command over table then that could be like

```
update a set a.ABadrestype = aa.[ABadrestype] from AdresBewoners a
join (
    select [ABid], [ABidA], [ABidB], [ABtypebewoner],  
       coalesce(case when (ABtypebewoner = 'K' and [ABadrestype] = -1) then null else [ABadrestype] end, 
               case when lag(ABadrestype) over (order by ABid) <> [ABadrestype] then 1 else 2 end) [ABadrestype]  from AdresBewoners
) aa on aa.ABid = a.ABid
```

Comment: I need the update statement. The records are already present in the database.

Comment: When running the update statement you provided I get this: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: one issue though: LAG inherently implies that the principal address (ABadrestype = 1) is supposed to be the first address when sorted on ID. But this isn't always the case (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d56f/2)...

Answer (score 0):

You can update it by below query. You can use joins with other tables and more complicated case clauses. I didn't understand your last requirement so you need to upgrade it a little bit.

```
update A
set A.ABadrestype = 
(CASE WHEN A.ABadrestype = 1 THEN 2 ELSE -1 END)
from Adresbewoners A
where A.ABtypebewoner = 'K'
```

Comment: This is not taking into account pre-existing addresses.